# duckduckgo.com to get the first N results for the specified phrase, using Net::HTTP ruby

Tags: ruby, net-http, duckduckgo

I am trying to parse results from duckduckgo search with Net::HTTP and store the links of the results of the array. However the result comes as a string. Any idea how get it any other type of data back as result or how to get the links from the string if there is no option to get the response in another type?

```
def getlinks(str, num_results)
    uri = URI.parse("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=#{str}")
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
end
```

Comment: See https://duckduckgo.com/api

Comment: Thanks Holger, but is only working for simple queries, for a query 'whytheluckystaff', returning empty result as they don't have proper api solution for search results, etc. this is throwing an empty json: 

https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=whytheluckystaff&format=json

Comment: DuckDockGo doesn't have then necessary rights to fully allow this (as explained on the site I linked to). As such, using the data you attempt to scrape there will very likely be copyright infringement.

Comment: Well, is for personal educational use, so should not breach any copyright, however wondering if there any solution for my issue.

Comment: Try to use gems like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) for net/http requests, and [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) in order to parse html response

Answer (score 0):

An example with [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=#{str}").read)
page.doc.css('a').first.attr(:href)
```

Comment: Thanks Kris, this is what I was looking for.